# MarkLogic 8 and server-side JavaScript - Debugging support

Tags: javascript, debugging, marklogic

Is there any plan to provide runtime debugging support for [server-side JavaScript](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/jsref)? 
Most of the XQuery API has been ported to JavaScript, but the "dbg" module, which gives you an entry point into query execution, has not.
As MarkLogic 8 embeds the [Google JavaScript engine](https://code.google.com/p/v8/), does this provide debugging hooks, which will allow third-party developers to write interactive debuggers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debugging, along with profiling and better logging, are on our roadmap. We’re looking at leveraging the debugger in the  [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools). Are there other IDEs or environments you’re using that we should be looking at as well? Feedback is much appreciated.

(As my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/563324/justin-makeig?tab=profile) indicates, I’m a Product Manager at MarkLogic.)

Comment: Thanks Justin, that's good news. We're using [Oxygen](http://oxygenxml.com/xml_developer.html) for our MarkLogic development, so that would be top of our wish list.

Comment: Debugging in Chrome Developer Tools would be cool. I use a jetbrains IDE. It would be cool having a node js marklogic plugin that knows about the MarkLogic functions.

Comment: It's still a high priority, but I don’t have a timetable for you.