# Marklogic 9 Server-Side JavaScript IDE

Tags: marklogic, serverside-javascript

Is there supported IDE for Marklogic 9 Server-Side JavaScript for development, debugging etc.,? According to this [MarkLogic 8 and server-side JavaScript - Debugging support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29965736/marklogic-8-and-server-side-javascript-debugging-support) post, a support for Chrome Dev Tools was on the roadmap but is it available now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest [Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/)

and the [MarkLogic pluging](https://developer.marklogic.com/code/sublime)

Comment: Thanks Hugo. Looking at the link you sent, it seems ML has support for Visual Studio Code and do you have any feedback about it? I'm interested in VS code as it has good integration with VSTS, which is my enterprise tool used in my organization.

Comment: We’d likely implement this using a standard debugging protocol such that it could be plugged into any IDE that supported that protocol.

Answer (score 0):

There is no debugging API for JavaScript today. This is something we’re looking closely at for a future release. (I’m a Product Manager at MarkLogic.)

Comment: Thanks Justin. Would help if you could get that in ASAP and help out the developers